# HTTP GET instead of HTTP Connect in .NET / C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

how do I do HTTP tunneling without using the HTTP Connect method but using HTTP Get method instead. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_tunneling I tried `IHttpClientFactory` and `RestSharp` both are establishing HTTP Connect. In the node.js request module, there is a param called `tunnel` which when false establish the connection using HTTP Get, how do I do something similar in .NET. Would really appreciate the help, have been looking for this for a while

Capture1 - C# when using a proxy server, http client creates a tunnel using HTTP Connect

```
Frame 331: 159 bytes on wire (1272 bits), 159 bytes captured (1272 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{262229C1-C486-4F85-BCC8-BFC96981C755}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_37:28:37 (dc:41:a9:37:28:37), Dst: TaicangT_80:60:30 (18:45:93:80:60:30)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: {myLocalIp}, Dst: {proxyServerIp}
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51694, Dst Port: 8888, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 105
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    CONNECT {host}:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n
    Host: {host}:443\r\n
    User-Agent: RestSharp/106.11.8.0\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: {url}:443]
    [HTTP request 1/1]
    [Response in frame: 341]
```

Capture2 - node.js with tunnel:false, this request also goes through the same proxy server but via a normal HTTP GET method and no tunnel

```
Frame 92: 393 bytes on wire (3144 bits), 393 bytes captured (3144 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{262229C1-C486-4F85-BCC8-BFC96981C755}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_37:28:37 (dc:41:a9:37:28:37), Dst: TaicangT_80:60:30 (18:45:93:80:60:30)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: {myLocalIp}, Dst: {proxyServerIp}
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51842, Dst Port: 8888, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 339
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET {url} HTTP/1.1\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15\r\n
    x-cache-proxyname: i-05ad6154426f07671\r\n
    host: {host}\r\n
    Connection: close\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: {url}]
    [HTTP request 1/1]
    [Response in frame: 96]
```

Comment: Tunnel is just port forwarding to allow you to get through a firewall. Inside your protected network you are getting blocked from accessing some servers.  Your link is suggesting you setup a two port server outside the firewall where you client can connect to one port and then second port is used to get to server blocked inside youy network.I do not understand your question. It looks like setting "tunnel to false" means you are not using a tunnel.  So the standard net HTTP method would be used.  Creating a tunnel like BOSH is using a special protocol not supported in the mangaged Net library.

Comment: yes so I have a proxy server through which I want to have all my HTTP requests. Now, when I am trying to do a http get requests via this proxy server on an https:// url, HttpClient in .Net by default establishes a connection using HTTP CONNECT method but I dont want httpclient to establish this tunnel and instead just to a normal HTTP GET via this proxy server.

Comment: Like in node.js request library https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback there is a parameter - tunnel, which when set to false, processes HTTPS requests as a normal HTTP GET via the supplied proxy server. I want to do similar in .Net/C#

Comment: Automatically a connection uses just a normal HTTPS.  Why do you think something else is being used?  Your proxy server is just a relay that reads data from one connection and sends to another connection.

Comment: I understand proxy server is just a relay, but can I force .Net HttpClient to not use HTTP Connect tunnel? just like I do in node.js request library?

Comment: maybe I am unable to explain it more clearly, but I do have Wireshark packet captures of the two different scenarios if that will help

Comment: The default HTTP header are different from c# that other apps.  A few things could be different 1) HTTP vs HTTPS  2) HTTP 1.0 vs HTTP 1.1 3) Version of TLS 4) Headers in message.5) Cookies

Comment: both are HTTP 1.1 which is very clear from Wireshark capture that I did. In both the method I am using an https:// url of the destination in. The protocol itself is different, in one it is establishing a tunnel using HTTP Connect Method and on one it is establishing a normal tcp connection to the proxy server and then HTTP GET to the final destination server. I want to emulate the HTTP GET method in .NET client too

Comment: HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  A TCP message consists of one or more datagrams (max size 1500 bytes).  So normally on sniffer you see both the TCP and combined HTTP.  If apps are using a Websocket then it looks on sniffer like TCP.  A HTTP connection is one request and one response.  A new connection is opened for each message.  A websocket you make one connection for multiple messages.

Comment: Hey first of all thanks for taking out time to reply. Really appreciate it.

Comment: But I am very certain both are plain HTTP reqeusts and not a websocket request, just that in one request its opening a tunnel using HTTP Connect  method as described in the Wiki I had shared earlier and in the other (node.js method with tunnel:false), it is just doing a normal GET via the proxy

Comment: If a tunnel was really being created the sniffer would show a different protocol instead of HTTPS.  If you post sniffer data for both results I will look and check differences.  I do not think it is a tunnel.

Comment: @jdweng hey I have updated the original question with two captures. For privacy reasons, I have removed actual IPs and Urls with variables. First capture is when I make the request from a c# http client (HttpClient or RestSharp) via a proxy and second one is when I make the sme request from node.js request module but with tunnel:false option. PS: Please excuse the formatting of the capture, I hope it is readable